# Locations of farthest matter

Tags: universe, redshift

Regarding matter that has the highest redshifts, do we see such matter in every general direction we look (relative to Earth: up down left right front back)?

Comment: Yes we do, and it looks like [this](https://www.google.dk/search?q=cmb&biw=1505&bih=1045&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFyb-s5ZrMAhUkL8AKHaqgAXMQ_AUIBigB).

Comment: That's CMB levels. I want redshifts.

Comment: The CMB is all at the same redshift (~1100), to a relative precision within $10^{-5}$, no matter if you look up, down, left, or right. We haven't observed anything with higher redshifts.

Comment: So if the measured CMB peak wavelength is ~2mm, then the originating CMB was ~2mm/1100 (~2um)?

Comment: More or less, yes. The answer depends a bit on whether you express intensity as a function of wavelength or frequency. I think 1 $\mu$m is considered the peak wavelength

Comment: Things closer to us appear bigger (duh), so most of what we see is the Milky way.  But if we ignore the close stuff, as I understand it, Matter is quite evenly spread out in every dimension, similar to CMB, which as adriancmenamin points out, came from matter.   The Universe appears quite uniform.  Very similar in every direction.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to see photons from "beyond" the cosmic microwave background (CMB), because (assuming our cosmology is generally correct) the CMB is the result of recombination of electrons with protons in the early universe. Photons from before that era were absorbed in the plasma.

Essentially then, the earliest matter we can see (in photonic terms) is this glowing hot hydrogen, but massively red-shifted so it looks like hydrogen at 3K.

We see the CMB in every direction.